How close position in Binance by API
I am looking for possibility of closing position regardless of whether at a profit or loss via API.
I tried something like that:
stop_order = self.client.futures_create_order(
            symbol=symbol,
            side=stop_side, #SELL if I have long position or BUY if short
            type=FUTURE_ORDER_TYPE_STOP_MARKET,
            closePosition=True,
            stopPrice=stop_price, #it is required but I would prefer "Market" price in this case
            test=True
        )

but I'm receiving error like that:
"Error canceling order: APIError(code=-2021): Order would immediately trigger."
or if I change to FUTURE_ORDER_TYPE_MARKET:
"Error canceling order: APIError(code=-4136): Target strategy invalid for orderType MARKET,closePosition true"
it's seems like binance API doesn't allow what I want.. but via page we can simply click "Market" and position would be close...

The error messages you’re encountering arise because Binance’s API handles closing positions differently than the web interface.
Order would immediately trigger (-2021) happens because FUTURE_ORDER_TYPE_STOP_MARKET is a stop order, which requires a stopPrice. However, the stop price cannot be immediately triggered by the current market price.
Target strategy invalid (-4136) occurs because FUTURE_ORDER_TYPE_MARKET does not support closePosition=True. That parameter is only valid for stop orders or take-profit orders.
You can use FUTURE_ORDER_TYPE_MARKET without closePosition.
You can create a market order with the correct quantity and side to close the position. Here’s how to do it-
positions = self.client.futures_account()['positions']
position = next((p for p in positions if p['symbol'] == symbol), None)

if position and float(position['positionAmt']) != 0:
    side = 'SELL' if float(position['positionAmt']) > 0 else 'BUY'  
    quantity = abs(float(position['positionAmt']))  

    close_order = self.client.futures_create_order(
        symbol=symbol,
        side=side,
        type='MARKET',
        quantity=quantity
    )
    print(f"Position closed: {close_order}")
else:
    print(f"No position found for {symbol}")


You're seeing that issue because the API is different. To close a position on Binance via API you need to use a MARKET order without the closePosition=True parameter. Check the open positions for the symbol, determine the side (BUY or SELL based on whether your position is short or long), and place a market order to close it. Here is a super useful tutorial.
    if position and float(position['positionAmt']) != 0:
    side = 'SELL' if float(position['positionAmt']) > 0 else 'BUY'
    quantity = abs(float(position['positionAmt']))
    client.futures_create_order(
        symbol='BTCUSDT',
        side=side,
        type='MARKET',
        quantity=quantity
    )
    print("Position closed successfully!")
else:
    print("No open position to close.")

